# Почему дефолтный антивирус в windows 10 удаляет все мои скомпилированные python программы?

Tags: python, компиляция

Какую бы программу не скомпилировал он всё удаляет. Чем они ему не угодили и как это исправить?

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/553288

Comment: Ну это бред какой то. Должен же быть нормальный способ. А как тогда другие люди ПО пишут?

Comment: О, это же винда!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего программа работает с жеским диском.
Случается это потому, что python не компилятор. А антивирус удаляет возможно потому что используется python 32bit вместо 64bit. Но и то не факт. Самому это открытие однажды стало неприятным. За легкость программирование теперь приходится расплачиваться.
А большинство людей (судя по всему) пишут для веб, поэтому не знают особых хлопот. Для ОС python не очень хорош. Он, как теперь мягко о нем говорят, "для прототипирования".
ПС: а дефолтный антивирус, мне кажется, лучше отключить, лучше использовать что-то получше.

Comment: дефолтный антивирус, по сравнению с "чем-то получше" очень даже ничего. тем более, если мыслящая голова на плечах есть

Comment: Я не много знаю java,попробывал скомпилировать программу на java в IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 и там такая же ситуация, прямо в программе выскакивает уведомление что windows defender что то там запрещает. Это что получается я и на java ничего написать не смогу?

Comment: @АндрейНикитин не подумал про java, но с java вероятна такая же проблема, ведь это виртуальная машина. Также вспоминаю, что и приложения, созданные на веб-фреймворках типа nodejs, вызывают те же жалобы антивирусов. Более того, простенькие приложения, скомпилированные на mingw в последнее время, вызывают такую же реакцию антивируса, на win10 как минимум, на win7 такого не наблюдал.

Comment: @АндрейНикитин кстати, это часто случается, когда вы создаете exe с открытым терминалом (ком.строкой). Как вариант попробуйте создать exe только с окном приложения, скрыв консоль, например, если вы используете pyinstaller для сборки, то в файле .spec нужно написать console=False.

Comment: @АндрейНикитин ах да, и наиболее прямая причина - это то, что любой неподписанный exe windows считает от непроверенного поставщика. Но цифровая подпись - это, как я понял, не бесплатно, да и в общем-то не очень нужно для небольших проектов. Главное чтобы ваш exe не содержал вирусы на virustotal.com. Плюс свой релизный exe вы можете присылать антивирусным компаниям на проверку (чтобы в дальнейшем на ваш exe они не срабатывали)... до тех пор, пока их антивирусы как следует не обновятся %) Насколько я знаю сегодня это самый верный, но самый абсурдный способ.

Comment: Эхххх понятно. Спасибо за информацию.